# Which trigonometric function I should use to generate the temperature with two peaks (i.e.one strong and one moderate peak)?

Tags: functions

I want to generate seasonal temperature of Bay of Bengal. I want to do this with a trigonometric function. Seasonal temperature of Bay of Bengal has two peaks. One major peak during April and another moderate peak in November. Which trigonometric function I should use to do this?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the same kind of question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112827/function-to-show-2-peaks-with-different-magnitudes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to show 2 peaks with different magnitudes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112827/function-to-show-2-peaks-with-different-magnitudes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to model periodic function is with Fourier series (though in your case the function seems approximately periodic only).

A simple second order approximation would be

$$a+b\cos\omega t+c\sin \omega t+d\cos 2\omega t+e\sin 2\omega t$$ where $\omega=\dfrac{2\pi}{12}$ if $t$ is in months.

You can find the extrema by canceling the derivative,

$$-b\sin\omega t+c\cos\omega t-d\sin2\omega t+e\cos2\omega t=0.$$

The coefficient $a$ will be the annual average and the remaining coefficients can be found by giving the positions and amplitudes of the two maxima, and solving a linear system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to interpolate the temperature using trigonometric functions given a set of known data points. For this you can use [trigonometric interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation).

Note that such an interpolation is not unique since your entire dataset consists of two points (the peak temperatures). You might want to add a lot more points if you want to correctly interpolate the data.

Comment: Actually, I want to generate the temperature data with the function. For example, T(t)=T+delta t*sin(o*t+a) can be used for generating the seasonal temperature data with one peak. I want a similar function which will generate the temperature similar to the graph I added.